# Registry Database in MultiTenant mode

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In the multi-tenanted environment (create and work with tenants), Registry Database is required to share the information in this database between the Gateway and Key Manager components.

So in the above line Which information need to be shared and where it  need to be shared?

Answer (score 0):

There is no special DB configurations for Multi-tenancy, Tenant related information will be stored in same DBs. And when you are clustering APIM you need to share databases among the nodes irrespective of tenant usage. You can refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager) guide for clustering.

Answer (score 0):

What is basically says is you need to do `step 8.c and 11` in `Installing and configuring the databases` section in [API Manager clustering guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0#ClusteringAPIManager2.0.0-ConfiguringtheGateway) for gateway and keymanager nodes as well.